# What's this start up item?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8

Recently I installed some software and uninstalled it. After that, the following pop window always show up when my desktop starts. I am using **Win8**. Could anyone tell me how to locate this bad start up item?

[image]

Comment: Probably something in one of the Startup folders, or in the [standard registry locations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179365).

Comment: Get a good virus scanner and let it go to work.

Comment: I have already checked all of the registry locations. Nothing strange found. I already have Microsoft Defender installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `regedit.exe`, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`

[image: RegEdit_Load]

and delete the highlighted string **Load**. This should fix the issue.

**Source:**

http://www.kapilarya.com/fix-getting-explorer-exe-error-on-windows-8-start-up